# i want call a function when click close browser ... element of button close browser?

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code ...i want call a function when click close browser at window.close().But not working..You can help me.Thank so much.<3

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var typeChange = false;
                $(document).on("keyup", 'form input', function (e) {
                    typeChange = true;
                });
                $(document).on("change", 'form select', function (e) {
                    typeChange = true;
                });
                function changeURL() {
                    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
                        if (typeChange) {
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                            e.returnValue = "";  
                        }
                    }, {once : true});
                }
               
                $(document).on('click', '.sidebar-menu a', function() {
                    changeURL();
                });
                // window.addEventListener("close", function () {
                //     changeURL();
                // });

                // window.close() = function() {
                //     changeURL();
                // };

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close... But there are two things:

1. You have to register the event listener for [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) when the page loads... Not when it is about to unload ;)
2. It won't be necessary to use an event handler on the `.sidebar-menu a` elements if those links are making the browser to navigate.

So here is the code that should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var typeChange = false;
  $(document).on("keyup", 'form input', function (e) {
      typeChange = true;
  });
  $(document).on("change", 'form select', function (e) {
      typeChange = true;
  });
  
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if (typeChange) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      e.returnValue = "";  
    }
  }, {once : true});
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid 'window' object doesn't have event 'close', howerver it has event 'beforeunload'. check belows codes copied from the below link.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Below artilce explains it in much more details
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-browser-or-tab-closing-in-javascript/#:~:text=A%20tab%20or%20window%20closing,the%20tab%20or%20the%20browser](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-browser-or-tab-closing-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=A%20tab%20or%20window%20closing,the%20tab%20or%20the%20browser).

Comment: Please don't write answers containing only code and links. Report in your answer the salient parts of the linked website, and provide an explanation of what your code does and why it works

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. But I thought those codes explain itself pretty clear.